# "Папа, ты всегда с нами". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обращение

**Папа, ты всегда с нами.**
Нужна ли запятая после слова "папа"?

Answer (score 3):

Запятая *нужна*, поскольку обращения на письме выделяются запятыми:

http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_180

После запятой обязателен *пробел*.